# Метод сжатия lz4, какой выбрать?

Tags: c++, c, compression

На оф. гитхабе lz4 есть несколько примеров и каждые из них используют разные методы сжатия или что? https://github.com/lz4/lz4/tree/dev/examples

Собственно, какой метод в данном примере использовать мне? И еще, в lz4 отсутствует ключ как я понял? 
Я хочу использовать lz4, когда размер байт будет >= 1000 байт

Comment: Там же в ридми идет ссылка на документацию… Метод сжатия в библиотеке только один - lz4. И про какой ключ идет речь? Это же не шифрование

Comment: Я документацию прочел, но там не сказано чем методы сжатия отличаются друг от друга.